# What is timer information shown by `ss -o`?

Tags: iproute, ss

`man ss` says `-o` shows timer information. What is timer information? I can't tell it from `ss -o` and `ss` without `-o`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add -o you will see it adds TCP packet timer information just as the manual states eg:

```
timer:(<timer_name>,<expire_time>,<retrans>)
timer:(keepalive,30sec,0)
```

[Refrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Timeout-based_retransmission)

Comment: What does "retrans" represent? and what does what it represents mean?

Comment: @Tim retrans = number of times the packet was re sent due to no acknowledgement packet before the expiration time.