# What do `<expire_time>` and `<retrans>` mean in the output of `ss -o`?

Tags: tcp, iproute, ss

[`ss -o` shows TCP timer in the following format:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499208/674)

```
timer:(<timer_name>,<expire_time>,<retrans>)
```

What do `<expire_time>` and `<retrans>` mean?

I found `<expire_time>` counts down to zero and then restart counting from some number again. Its starting value differs from TCP socket to TCP socket.

`<retrans>` seems always zero for all the TCP sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expire_time` is the time left until the timer expires. The TCP stack in the Linux kernel supports a number of timers, and they all have an expiration time.

`retrans` is the number of retransmissions which have occurred. TCP implementations  [retransmit packets they believe have been lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Timeout-based_retransmission); they counts these retransmissions so that they will know when to give up. You shouldn’t see this too often; one way to force it is to try to open a connection on a port which isn’t rejected immediately, *e.g.* (based on an example in one of your previous questions):

```
curl http://www.google.com:9000
```

If you run that, you’ll see `curl` sitting there for a while, and `ss -o` will show a `SYN-SENT` entry with an increasing retransmission count. You’ll also see the back-off applied in such circumstances: the initial expiration time will increase every time the packet is retransmitted.

Comment: Is the expire_time reset when something is transmitted (whether retransmitted or not)?

Comment: Yes, it resets when a packet is transmitted.