# What is "inet prefix"?

Tags: iproute, ss

```
$ ss  'state = established'
Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "state".
Cannot parse dst/src address.
```

What is "inet prefix"?

What is a valid "inet prefix"?

Comment: The syntax is `ss state established` rather than `ss  'state = established'` I think (take a look at the `USAGE EXAMPLES` section of the man page)

Comment: I can only guess that. So I ask What is "inet prefix"? What is valid "inet prefix"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inet they mean a "network socket address" (inet4 or inet6 vs unix)
By prefix they mean the IP (1.2.3.4) of the IP:port pair required for a socket.

The manual written by the application author is [more clear](https://www.cyberciti.biz/files/ss.html) than the Debian maintainers version and lists examples like

```
dst prefix:port
dst 10.0.0.0/24:22
```

The IP may include a mask (/24) making prefix a reasonable abstraction.
Notably you did not ask how to fix your syntax and there is already a comment on that so I'll just keep on point with this answer.

Comment: There is no "Debian maintainers" manual.  [The manual in the Debian package](https://sources.debian.org/src/iproute2/4.20.0-2/man/man8/ss.8/) is [the one in the original software maintained by Stephen Hemminger](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/master/man/man8/ss.8), unaltered.

Comment: Thanks. How can I find all the manuals written by the application author for all the commands in lprouter2?

Comment: @JdeBP "AUTHOR
       ss was  written  by  Alexey  Kuznetsov,
       <kuznet@ms2.inr.ac.ru>.

       This manual page was written by Michael
       Prokop <mika@grml.org> for  the  Debian         project (but may be used by others)."

Comment: @Tim search the www

Comment: It is the manual page in the original software, _as I showed you by pointing right to it_, that has been modified by a fair number of people in the decade and a bit since it was first written, and Debian takes it from the original software as-is.

Answer (score 1):

The IP prefix, is the "192.168.1.0" part of 192.168.1.0/24, 24 being the suffix tells how many bits are in the entire address. A valid inet prefix is any prefix that matches the network you are attempting to communicate on that also aligns with the subnet. Whether that is a 10. or a 192. or other. network for example.

In your use case the error message you received was erroneous, as it was just ss's best guess as to what you were asking it to accomplish. Do to the fact that the syntax was off.